# HSV space for multicolor object

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I would like to detect this gate below, ideally the entire gate. I have played around for hours with a trackbar script but I am just not finding the right color space. I found other threads that just track yellow and not even that is working.. This is my code:

```
def track():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('../files/sub/gate_mission1.mp4')
    while True:
        _, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow('img', frame)
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

        lower = np.array([20, 93, 0])
        upper = np.array([45, 255, 255])

        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cv2.drawContours(frame, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

Maybe there is a way to just remove all the blue/greenish too im not sure? What are my options here?

[image]

Comment: Orange and green are nearly opposite colors. How come you can’t use hue to separate them?

Comment: How do you mean exactly?

Comment: Try these settings: `hMin = 19 , sMin = 57, vMin = 138` and `hMax = 92 , sMax = 255, vMax = 255`.

Comment: Thanks that works pretty ok. Could you maybe get me the settings for only the yellow parts and I can see which works best. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me by thresholding in LAB colorspace in Python/OpenCV. According to Wikipedia at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space "The a* axis is relative to the green–red opponent colors, with negative values toward green and positive values toward red." So we ought to get reasonably good separation for your green and reddish colors.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load images
img = cv2.imread('gate.jpg')

# convert to LAB
lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)

# set black ranges
lower = (130,105,100)
upper = (170,170,160)

# threshold on black
result = cv2.inRange(lab, lower, upper)

# save output
cv2.imwrite('gate_thresh.jpg', result)

# display results
cv2.imshow('thresh',result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Threshold Image

[image]

Comment: So that is pretty good, but the issue im gonna get here is the reflection. So I think I need to remove the water blue/greenish well enough such that the small space between the actually bar and the reflection of the bar creates a separation in the contour. Alternatively just detect the yellow posts and detect the two contours with the largest area.

Comment: Try using two narrower sets of inRange() for different colors and combine the two thresholds.